# Is there a reason why launchUrl works by itself, and not inside a dart function?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, serverless, square

When I have code similar to this, the application works as expected as desktop.

```
launchUrl(uri);
setState(() {
    paymentLaunched = true;
});
```

But, when I had an async function that included `launchUrl` function, nothing happened on the client application on a mobile device. The user stays on the current webpage. Desktop doesn't have an issue launching the URL, only the mobile devices.

```
getSquareCheckoutLink().then((uri) {
  if (uri != null) {
    launchUrl(uri);
    setState(() {
      paymentLaunched = true;
    });
  }
});
```

Here is the implementation of `getSquareCheckoutLink()`:

```
Future<Uri?> getSquareCheckoutLink() async {
    final String idemKey = const Uuid().v1();
    final SquareAPI api = production;
    List<LineItem> lineItemList = [];
    BaseMoneyPrice youthPrice = const BaseMoneyPrice(0, "USD");
    BaseMoneyPrice adultPrice = const BaseMoneyPrice(2000, "USD");
    BaseMoneyPrice seniorPrice = const BaseMoneyPrice(1000, "USD");
    if (childTickets > 0) {
      lineItemList
          .add(LineItem('Youth Ticket', childTickets.toString(), youthPrice));
    }
    if (adultTickets > 0) {
      lineItemList
          .add(LineItem("Adult Ticket", adultTickets.toString(), adultPrice));
    }
    if (seniorTickets > 0) {
      lineItemList.add(
          LineItem("Senior Ticket", seniorTickets.toString(), seniorPrice));
    }
    if (lineItemList.isEmpty) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return const AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Please select tickets to purchase"),
              content: Text(
                  "You do not have any tickets selected to purchase. Please choose ticket(s) for the performance."),
            );
          });
      return null;
    }
    final data = SquareData(idemKey, OrderData(api.locationId, lineItemList));
    http
        .post(Uri.parse("/.netlify/functions/square-payments"),
            body: data.toJson())
        .then((response) {
      final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body)["payment_link"];
      return Uri.parse(Uri.encodeFull(jsonResponse["url"]));
    });

    return null;
  }
```

Not sure why the application is behaving like this. I was wondering if I was missing something. I never had this issue before while using `url_launcher` flutter package. Tried different techniques such as:

- ensuring the URL was encoded
- using async/await
- verified the link was getting returned
- used a text widget to show the response data

You can use this test data for the request if you need it.

```
{"idempotency_key":"512345koo-3479-1hgj-a1c7-8f23ghjk32ac","order":{"location_id":"LQA9TJT2MDK33","line_items":[{"name":"Adult Ticket","quantity":"1","base_price_money":{"amount":2000,"currency":"USD"}}]}}
```

If you want to test my deployment on your mobile device, you will see the behavior I am mentioning.

[Link to preview site](https://deploy-preview-18--elaborate-fudge-f549c7.netlify.app/#/performances)

1. Add an adult ticket
2. Click purchase
3. A new webpage should appear after a min or so to checkout

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the text widget as a child in an inkwell to launch the URL as workaround. launchUrl seem to work when it is not dependent on another process to provide it the URI.

Here is the changes I made:

```
Center(
   child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {
         launchUrl(link);
         setState(() {
           msg = "";
         });
      },
      child: Text(
         msg,
         style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.blueAccent),
      ),
  )),
```

```
final uri = await getSquareCheckoutLink();
if (uri != null) {
   await launchUrl(uri);
   setState(() {
      link = uri;
      msg = "Click here to pay";
      paymentLaunched = true;
   });
 } else {
   setState(() {
       msg = "Error: Try refreshing page";
  });
}
```

Still not sure why the first launchUrl call after obtaining the URI successfully doesn't work. However, the workaround seems fail-proof as long as the response is not come back as null or with an API exception.

If anyone understands why this is happening, please shed some light on this. Bug?